# ¿Qué es Header Enrichment?

Tags: nodejs, http

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación web con `node js express` y quisiera saber:

- ¿Que es Header Enrichment ?
- ¿Para que sirve?
- ¿En que lo puedo usar?

Me habían comentado que es para reconocer a mi cliente final, y que podía obtener su dirección IP.

Sería genial si también se pudiera reconocer el número de celular en caso que
consuman la aplicación web desde el celular.

Comment: Son muy buenas preguntas pero son demasiadas en una sola. Creo que deberías separarlas y detallar más qué es lo que necesitas saber. Además sería bueno que nos dieras un poco de contexto de lo que estás intentando hacer. Si la dejas tal y como está podría cerrarse por ser demasiado amplia.

Comment: la pregunta principal es clara y es lo que quiero saver

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia y no muestra ningún tipo de investigación previa al solo argumentar "Me habían comentado".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El concepto de "Header Enrichement" es genérico aunque está muy ligado a la tecnología móvil, de los tiempos en que se desarrolló la tecnología WAP.

Consiste en la introducción de HTTP Headers extra que proveen información que no estaba presente en el mensaje HTTP original.

La introducción es realizada por un "Proxy" y puede ocurrir en las dos direcciones de la comunicación: petición HTTP y respuesta HTTP.

En los tiempos de WAP el proxy era utilizado sí o sí por los terminales, ya que el WAP proxy realizaba una adaptación (supuestamente) perfecta de los contenidos disponibles en Internet para navegadores.

En tiempos modernos el tráfico es interceptado de manera transparente (Vodafone lo llamaba: "Web Optimization" y "Video Optimization", interceptando y comprimiendo/cortando los contenidos. "Optimization" no dejaba de ser un eufemismo para el cliente ya que el objetivo era reducir el tráfico final en las estaciones base y con ello ahorrar dinero al reducir la frecuencia de actualización de capacidad y tecnología)

La introducción del MSN (Mobile Subscriber Number) era una práctica muy habitual en tiempos WAP en los cuales el operador móvil llenaba los terminales de aplicaciones propias y tarificaba el acceso de dichas aplicaciones a distintos servicios. La tarificación se basaba en el análisis del header que contenía el MSN.

En los últimos 2 años vuelve a ofrecerse una tarificación por servicio lo que ha puesto de moda nuevamente el "Header Enrichment" ya que el tráfico se enruta por distintos canales según la subscripción del cliente y el destino/tipo de tráfico (p.ej: accedder gratis a todos los contenidos de Orange TV con la tarifa XXX).

El MSN nunca se envía en comunicación abierta a nodos de Internet.

¿Dónde se configura el Header Enrichment? En los nodos de red: Cisco, Juniper, Citrix (antiguamente ByteMobile), etc. Es decir: la configuración del Header Enrichment está bajo estricto control del Operador Móvil/Proveedor de Servicios de Internet.

Si la aplicación de la pregunta está bajo control del Operador Móvil o de una empresa con la que tenga un acuerdo, la recepción de los "enriched Headers" será posible (incluyendo cosas como IP, MSN)

Al header se accederá como a cualquier otro HTTP header una vez sabido cual es su nombre, formato y contenido.

El formato y contenido de dichos "headers" estará determinado por el Operador Móvil dueño del Proxy que realiza el "enriquecimiento".

Nota: Hoy día el concepto de proxy en los operadores moviles (y/o proveedores de servicios de internet) se esconde/encuentra en nodos como DPI (Deep Packet Inspection) y otros.

Comment: Gracias por la informacion

Comment: Que buena respuesta. Coincido. La unica forma para ver el msn seria que el app la controle el operador.

Answer (score 0):

**¿Qué es Header Enrichment?**                                                         El “Header Enrichment” es un proceso que añade información adicional a los encabezados HTTP en las solicitudes o respuestas de red, especialmente en redes móviles.

**¿Para qué sirve?** Sirve para que los operadores de red y proveedores de servicios puedan identificar a los usuarios y sus dispositivos, personalizar servicios y realizar una facturación más precisa basada en el uso.

**¿En qué lo puedo usar?** Puedes usarlo en la gestión de tráfico de datos móviles, análisis de uso, personalización de servicios al cliente y sistemas de facturación en redes de telecomunicaciones.